# Textbox border color for field missing using CSS

Tags: css

I have web page with multiple text boxes, I have added Ajax-ValidateCalloutExtender to validate text boxes and it is working fine.

I have added CCS to highlight text boxes to be **"Red"** for field missing but it does not highlight the text box border to be **"Red"** .

See my coding below,

```
<td>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtPlanName" runat="server" Width="250px" BorderColor="#669999"                     
                     BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter your Plan Name" Display="None" SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtPlanName" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
 <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender1" TargetControlID="RequiredFieldValidator1" Enabled="true" runat="server" HighlightCssClass="tkpdna_req_field_highlight" ></asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>         
</td>
```

**CSS**

```
 .tkpdna_req_field_highlight {    
 border-color:Red;
 border-style:solid;    
}
```

Comment: You might have to give it a border-width as well, for which you may use the shorthand: `border: 1px solid red`.

Comment: have you checked that in the case of an error the tkpdna_req_field_highlight class actually gets added to the textbox element??

Answer (score 1):

you're missing `border-width` (which is 0 as default, this is why you don't see it).
do it as following:

```
.tkpdna_req_field_highlight {    
    border:solid 1px red !important;
}
```

adding `!important` to force override of previous style values.

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Try the !important override:

```
.tkpdna_req_field_highlight {    
 border: 1px solid red !important;    
}
```

Next to that, make sure that the textarea is rendered properly and the class attribute including the classname is added to the textbox like so:

```
<textarea class="tkpdna_req_field_highlight" ... ></textarea>
```

Comment: Hi Gillian, it is not showing anything(am using asp text boxes). i tried using class/CssClass but no luck...

Comment: May I see the rendered text box? (when you look at view-source)

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="txtPlanName" runat="server" Width="250px" BorderColor="#669999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: In the rendered textbox there is no reference to the class .tkpdna_req_field_highlight

Comment: You need to add this to the textbox: CssClass="tkpdna_req_field_highlight" />

Comment: i have added the refference but still not showing color..dont know what seems to be the problem now

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="txtPlanName" runat="server" Width="250px" BorderColor="#669999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CssClass="tkpdna_req_field_highlight"

Comment: Do you have this page somewhere online? Also, if you're using firefox or crome, you can inspect element with the right mouse button. From there you can see if the class is being loaded

Comment: <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender1" TargetControlID="RequiredFieldValidator1" Enabled="true" runat="server" CssClass="tkpdna_req_field_highlight" ></asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>